# what is a mortgage gift exchange?

Tags: mortgage

How do I do a gift exchange on a mortgage? my ex husband is on the mortgage loan and we are both on the title. he wants to turn over the mortgage to me, by doing a gift exchange, how does that work?

Comment: Where did you hear of "mortgage gift exchange"? Was it advice someone gave you? It's not a phrase that comes up as a common one used in finance.

Comment: +@joetaxpayer: I think I may know what "mortgage gift exchange" wax referring to -- see my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the lender used two peoples income, debts, and credit history to loan both of you money to purchase a house.

The only way to get a person off the loan, is to get a new loan via refinancing. The new loan will then be based on the income, debt, and credit history of one person. There is no paperwork you can sign, or the ex-spouse can sign, that will force the original lender to remove somebody from the loan.

There is one way that a exchange of money between the two of you could work:

- Value of house 200K
- current loan balance 120K
- amount of loan you can afford based on your income, debts and credit history: 100K
- Your ex-spouse could write a check for 20K before the settlement of the refinance so that you can add to the equity/down payment.

The ex-spouse will have to sign paperwork to prove that it is not a loan that you will have to payback. I picked the number 20K for a reason. If the amount of the payment is above 14K they will have to document for the IRS that this is a gift, and the amount above 14K will be counted as part of their estate when they die. If the amount of the payment is less than 14K they don't even have to tell the IRS.

If the ex-souse has remarried or you have remarried the multiple payments can be constructed to exceed the 14K limit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing since I don't know the term, but it sounds like you're asking about the technique whereby a loan is used to gather multiple years' gift allowance into a single up-front transfer. For the subsequent N years, the giver pays the installments on the loan for the recipient, at a yearly amount small enough to avoid triggering Gift Tax. You still have to pay income tax on the interest received (even though you're giving them the money to pay you), and you *must* charge a certain minimum interest (or more accurately, if you charge less than that they tax you as if the loan was earning that minimum).

Historically this was used by relatively wealthy folks, since the cost of lawyers and filing the paperwork and bookkeeping was high enough that most folks never found out this workaround existed, and few were moving enough money to make those costs worthwhile. But between the "Great Recession" and the internet, this has become much more widely known, and there are services which will draw up standard paperwork, have a lawyer sanity-check it for your local laws, file the official mortgage lien (not actually needed unless you want the recipient to also be able to write off the interest on their taxes), and provide a payments-processing service if you do expect part or all of the loan to be paid by the recipient. Or whatever subset of those services you need.

I've done this. In my case it cost me a bit under $1000 to set up the paperwork so I could loan a friend a sizable chunk of cash and have it clearly on record as a loan, not a gift. The amount in question was large enough, and the interpersonal issues tricky enough, that this was a good deal for us. Obviously, run the numbers.

Websearching "family loan"  will find much more detail about how this works and what it can and can't do, along with services specializing in these transactions.

NOTE: If you are actually selling something, such as your share of a house, this dance may or may not make sense. Again, run the numbers, and if in doubt get expert advice rather than trusting strangers on the web. (Go not to the Internet for legal advice, for it shall say both mu and ni.)